# Mining with 1.06GH/s

Tags: blocks, mining-pools

So right now I'm using 2miners and I rented 1.06GH/s to mine Ethereum. It says every 2 months I should find a block solo at 11k reward. Pool mining I'll get .55eth if pool finds a block now. It never says when a pool with find a block and I need to mine with a pool for the daily payout so I can keep buying the same hashpower. My question is How long in a pool will it take to find a block? Is there a pool better than 2miners out there? The only other pool I use (For the last 3 days) is antpool to get ltc+doge.

Oh, My end game is to keep investing the daily earnings and withdraw the blocks. When I have enough I will buy a asic machine built for either or gpus to mine diff coins.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the ["Top Miners by Blocks"](https://etherscan.io/stat/miner?range=7&blocktype=blocks) chart to get an idea of the largest mining pools and how many blocks they mined over a given period of time. For this calculation you can assume a constant [average blocktime](https://etherscan.io/chart/blocktime) and therefore a constant amount of [blocks per day](https://ycharts.com/indicators/ethereum_blocks_per_day).

So given the 2miners (PPLNS) pool supplied ~2.35% of the blocks over the last 7 days and ~6500 blocks where mined (by the whole network) per day, you can calculate an average of ~152.75 blocks per day mined by the 2miners pool.

I don't know how often they pay out the rewards and that certainly differs from pool to pool. Usually the payouts are batched, so you will get your accumulated rewards once the pool processes the payouts. So if you are looking to receive your rewards as frequently as possible, you will need to look at the specific payout scheme of the pool.